# Multi dynamic combobox populated with mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, combobox

Database

```
$mySql = "SELECT field FROM fields";
$result = mysql_query($mySql);
```

Html:

```
<select id="combo1" class="combo" data-index="1">
<option></option>
<?php
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value=" .$r['field '] . ">".$r['field '] ."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<div id="combos"></div>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('body').on('change', '.combo', function() {
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
if (selectedValue !== '' && $(this).find('option').size() > 8) {
var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;
$('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();
newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
$('#combos').append(newComboBox);
}
});
</script>
```

Questions:
This code is creating comboboxes with my database talble fields.
My problem is that fields cant be repeated when selected once.
Where is the error in the code? Or what am I thiking wrong?

It was supposed to be like that: http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/1/

Comment: what u get when u console.log(selectedValue) ??

Comment: where should I write it ? alert(selectedValue) seems fine. It returns the selected field

Comment: when u  alert(selectedValue).. what r u getting ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are checking `size() > 8`, so for it work there must be more than 8 options. Change that to `size() > 2`. Other than that your code will work.

The other problem is you aren't wrapping the option values in quotes. Add quotes:

```
echo "<option value=\"" .$r['field'] . "\">".$r['field'] ."</option>";
```

You also have a space after field:

```
 $r['field ']
 //       ^ here, remove that
```

Comment: But there is more than 8 options. Query returns 9 options.

Comment: Show the HTML that your PHP outputs.

Comment: I dont know if is that what you mean: [link](http://s8.postimage.org/jhl3mhzvn/combo.png) As you see, the comoboboxes are repeating the values.

Comment: @skdnewbie see my edit, you are missing quotes around the values.

Comment: See my other edit, you have a space in the field name so it won't find the field.

Comment: fixed, but still the same :s

Comment: Change `val` to `value` in the `find()`.

Comment: @skdnewbie as I said in my answer unless you change to `size()>2` it will only work on +8 options...

Answer (score 1):

on site example is

```
<option val="Opt1">
```

In your html it's `value` attribute instead of `val` so you need to change

```
newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
```

to

```
newComboBox.find('option[value="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
```

Comment: And you are right :D but, why has worked the other example that i posted with fidle? :s

Comment: check fidle html-code - attribute name is `val` so correct selector is `otion[val=""]` and you using attribute `value`

Comment: ok, new problem now. After this change, i can only "open" 3 checkboxes. The point was going until no more options available

Comment: I might know where it is. `size()` . Yap fixed to size()>2